# Adding special characters to slug?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, slug, characters

Is it possible to prevent WP from stripping out certain characters when customizing a URL?  For example, affiliate ids usually have something like `?id=something`.  Customizing a content's slug with that results in the `?` being converted to a `\`.  Any way to keep WP from rewriting the URL?

Comment: I don't understand the motivation. Why do you care if the URL of the post is example.com>id=45, how does it serve identifying the affiliate?

Comment: It's how affiliate systems work - part of the url identifies the referrer, allowing them to earn a commission on a sale.  An example url would be:

`domain.com/product?id=something`

I'm trying to figure out a way to hardcode an id to a URL when the norm for WordPress slugs is to strip out characters.

Comment: but the id of the affiliate should be in the referring link, it doesn't have to be part of the slug. One will use example.com/test?id=1 and the other example.com/test?id=2 but the slug itself can be "test", there is no need for a different slug for each affiliate.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to fix a slug (and thus a specific product) with a single, specific affiliate - hence my question here.  Sorry if I was not clear about that.

Comment: Then I guess Milos's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add query string arguments to permalinks, use [`the_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) filter:

```
function append_query_string( $url ) {
    return add_query_arg( 'id', 'something', $url );
}
add_filter( 'the_permalink', 'append_query_string' );
```

Comment: How would that work if there are multiple query strings?  Maybe a custom field could be utilized.

Comment: There must be a way to append the contents of a custom field to slug, no?  That might be a good way to do it.